# C# LINQ query to sum rows by condition and add to existing list

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following List of data.

```
 var data = new List<SummaryTabData>()
        {
            new SummaryTabData(){ LP = "LP_1", assetClass = "Asset_CFD_Long", avgSlippagePts = 54.23} ,
            new SummaryTabData(){ LP = "LP_1", assetClass = "Asset_FX_Long", avgSlippagePts = 61.41} ,
            new SummaryTabData(){ LP = "LP_1", assetClass = "Asset_FX_Short", avgSlippagePts = 11.48} ,
            new SummaryTabData(){ LP = "LP_1", assetClass = "Asset_CFD_Short", avgSlippagePts = 63.51} ,

            new SummaryTabData(){ LP = "LP_2", assetClass = "Asset_FX_Long",  avgSlippagePts = 6.51} ,            
            new SummaryTabData(){ LP = "LP_2", assetClass = "Asset_FX_Short", avgSlippagePts = 13.51}
        };
```

My goal is to add an additional row for every pair of **Asset_CFD_long/Asset_CFD_short** and **Asset_FX_Long/Asset_FX_Short** for every type of LP. Sometimes there might be either 2 or 4 asset classes like you can see in the example snip

The final result should look something like this.

```
var data = new List<SummaryTabData>()
            {
                new SummaryTabData(){ LP = "LP_1", assetClass = "Asset_CFD_Long", avgSlippagePts = 54.23} ,
                new SummaryTabData(){ LP = "LP_1", assetClass = "Asset_CFD_Short", avgSlippagePts = 63.51} ,

                // that is the new row added to the collection for LP_1 CFD
                new SummaryTabData(){ LP = "LP_1", assetClass = "CFD_Total", avgSlippagePts = 117.74} ,

                new SummaryTabData(){ LP = "LP_1", assetClass = "Asset_FX_Long", avgSlippagePts = 61.41} ,
                new SummaryTabData(){ LP = "LP_1", assetClass = "Asset_FX_Short", avgSlippagePts = 11.48} ,

                // that is the new row added to the collection for LP_1 FX
                new SummaryTabData(){ LP = "LP_1", assetClass = "FX_Total", avgSlippagePts = 72.89} ,

                new SummaryTabData(){ LP = "LP_2", assetClass = "Asset_FX_Long",  avgSlippagePts = 6.51} ,
                new SummaryTabData(){ LP = "LP_2", assetClass = "Asset_FX_Short", avgSlippagePts = 13.51},

                // that is the new row added to the collection for LP_2 FX
                new SummaryTabData(){ LP = "LP_2", assetClass = "FX_Total", avgSlippagePts = 20.02},
            };
```

The data is not sorted. Do you know for some kind of LINQ query that can do this or I should go with the traditional for loop approach ?

Comment: The requirement is a little strange. however I'm not judging. essentially you'll want to `Groupby` then `Sum`,. then iterate the results, then go back to the list and find the last occurrence of each group, then insert.

Comment: @TheGeneral could you provide a code snippet ?

Comment: If it's not sorted, how do you know which two items to connect together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirements are a little strange, however the assumption is the LP groups can be ordered in any way

**Updated**

```
var groups = data
   .Select(x => new { Asset = x.assetClass.Split("_")[1], Summary = x })
   .GroupBy(x => new { x.Asset, x.Summary.LP });

var list = new List<SummaryTabData>();

foreach (var group in groups)
{
   list.AddRange(group.Select(x => x.Summary).ToList());

   list.Add(new SummaryTabData()
   {
      assetClass = $"{group.Key.Asset}_Total",
      LP = group.Key.LP,
      avgSlippagePts = group.Sum(x => x.Summary.avgSlippagePts)
   });

}

foreach (var item in list)
   Console.WriteLine($"{item.LP}, {item.assetClass}, {item.avgSlippagePts}");
```

**Output**

```
LP_1, Asset_FX_Short, 11.48
LP_1, Asset_FX_Long, 61.41
LP_1, FX_Total, 72.89
LP_1, Asset_CFD_Short, 63.51
LP_1, Asset_CFD_Long, 54.23
LP_1, CFD_Total, 117.74
LP_2, Asset_FX_Short, 13.51
LP_2, Asset_FX_Long, 6.51
LP_2, FX_Total, 20.02
```

In all likely hood there are other ways to do this

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/J7l0ml)

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;using System.Linq;

namespace TestConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        public class SummaryTabData
        {
            public string LP { get; set; }
            public string assetClass { get; set; }
            public double avgSlippagePts { get; set; }
        }

        public enum AssetClassType
        {
            Cfd,
            Fx
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var data = new List<SummaryTabData>()
            {
                new SummaryTabData(){ LP = "LP_1", assetClass = "Asset_CFD_Long", avgSlippagePts = 54.23} ,
                new SummaryTabData(){ LP = "LP_1", assetClass = "Asset_FX_Long", avgSlippagePts = 61.41} ,

                new SummaryTabData(){ LP = "LP_1", assetClass = "Asset_FX_Short", avgSlippagePts = 11.48} ,
                new SummaryTabData(){ LP = "LP_1", assetClass = "Asset_CFD_Short", avgSlippagePts = 63.51} ,

                new SummaryTabData(){ LP = "LP_2", assetClass = "Asset_FX_Long",  avgSlippagePts = 6.51} ,
                new SummaryTabData(){ LP = "LP_2", assetClass = "Asset_FX_Short", avgSlippagePts = 13.51}
            };
            var expectedResult = GetSummaries(data);

        }

        private static List<SummaryTabData> GetSummaries(List<SummaryTabData> data)
        {
            var datas = data.Select(x => new
            {
                x.LP,
                x.assetClass,
                x.avgSlippagePts,
                AssetClassType = x.assetClass.Contains("CFD") ? AssetClassType.Cfd : AssetClassType.Fx
            }).GroupBy(x => new { x.AssetClassType, x.LP })
                .Select(x => new
                {
                    assetClass = x.Key.AssetClassType == AssetClassType.Cfd ? "CFD_Total" : "FX_Total",
                    sum = x.Sum(z => z.avgSlippagePts),
                    Lp = x.Key.LP,
                    SummaryTabData = x.Select(z => new SummaryTabData()
                    {
                        assetClass = z.assetClass,
                        LP = z.LP,
                        avgSlippagePts = z.avgSlippagePts
                    })
                }).ToList();

            List<SummaryTabData> result = new List<SummaryTabData>();

            foreach (var groupData in datas)
            {
                result.AddRange(groupData.SummaryTabData);

                result.Add(new SummaryTabData
                {
                    assetClass = groupData.assetClass,
                    LP = groupData.Lp,
                    avgSlippagePts = groupData.sum
                });
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

I think this code can help you with your problem,
I  used LINQ for the first part of the code, on the last part of the code I couldn't avoid using foreach.